# get date with timezone javascript

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

I want to compare date and with date in user timezone after user's login.
I get user's timezone with php.
now How to I take current date/time in javascript of user's timezone current time.

@everyone answered:
I don't need current local system timezone or offset in seconds.
I need users current time with dynamic time I get in php.
For example:
I have 'Asia/Kolkata' or 'America/Denver' or whatever that will be dynamic by php.
Now I can save it to hidden value so that I can get it with Javascript
and than I need current date of this timezone same like Javascript gives date object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// date() function
var currDate = new Date()
var n = currDate.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: This will give me localsystem date that I don't want.
and n will give me offset.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses the system's time zone. You can get the offset via [GetTimezoneOffset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var date=<?php echo date("Y/m/d")?>
</script>
```

this might help you

Comment: This doesn't take into account the timezone of he user

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<script>
    var date = '<?php echo date("Y/m/d");?>';
    alert(date);
</script>
```

deeply you can also try like this

```
var today = new Date();  
var localoffset = -(today.getTimezoneOffset()/60);
var destoffset = -4; 

var offset = destoffset-localoffset;
var d = new Date( new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000);
alert(d);
```

there you can get

Answer (score 0):

You can send UTC string

```
strtotime("2013-02-08 00:00:00");
```

After that you would have seconsd, that you can convert simple to JS Date:

```
var utcString = 1360263600 /*AJAX result must be here*/;
new Date(utcString*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date Object of JavaScript to get user's local system..

for example you can use following:

```
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getTime();
alert(time);
```

this will alert the the number of milliseconds since midnight.

You can send this time to your server and compare the both.

For more functions and details you can visit [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I am from Taiwan and it returns "+8" for me.

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/9maczqyy/3/)

**JS**

```
function timezone() {
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    var minutes = Math.abs(offset);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var prefix = offset < 0 ? "+" : "-";
    return prefix+hours;
}


$('#result1').html(timezone());
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Result**

```
+8
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [moment.js with moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/).

Then you can do something like:

```
moment().tz("Asia/Kolkata").format();
```